# Data arrangement ANOVA

Tags: anova, stata

I am using Stata to perform an ANOVA analysis. I would like to ask for help on how to arrange data. This is a texture analysis and I have four data sets (four different time points) [image]

Comment: You need to ask a specific question.

Comment: I would like to know how should I arrange data to perform the test in Stata. Thank you.

Comment: Could you edit your question to say so, please?